# Getting a content script to append image on page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've just start out learning how to make extensions for google chrome.  I have a very basic understanding so far, so I wanted to try something small.

Right now I am trying to get an image to append to a specific div on a specific page everytime that page loads.  The extension loads properly but, the javascript code never seems to run and the image never gets loaded.

This is the manifest.json file I have so far:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Icon Creator",
    "description": "Creates a custom icon for page",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["file:///home/tijko/documents/learning/javascript/test_page.html"],
        "css": ["sample.css"],
        "js":["trial.js"]
    }
    ],
    "icons": {"icon": "icon.jpg"},
    "web_accessible_resources":["trial.js"]
}
```

and the javascript:

```
var test = function() {
    custom_icon = document.createElement("img");
    target = document.getElementById("location");
    custom_icon.src = "icon.png";
    target.appendChild(custom_icon);
}
test()
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Are you trying to load your own extension's `icon.png`? Right now you are trying to load `icon.png` on the domain and path of the local page. Instead, you should do:

```
custom_icon.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("icon.png");
```

to refer to your extension's `icon.png`.

**Also**, you must list `icon.png` in your `web_accessible_resources`. Furthermore, you *don't* need to list `trial.js` in your `web_accessible_resources` (except for [*very* specialized use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526995/can-a-site-invoke-a-browser-extension)).

Finally, you need to approve your extension for access to `file://` pages by checking the appropriate box under your extension's listing in `chrome://extensions`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've gone ahead and made an edit to the `custom_icon.src = chrome.extension.getURL("icon.jpg")` and made sure to remove `trial.js` from `web_accessible_resources` then put in `icon.jpg`.  Lastly, `file://` was already checked under `chrome://extensions`.  Still no image with these changes.

Comment: @tijko Are you actually calling `test`? That is, is your JavaScript sample your entire content script? You need a `test()` invocation at the end or your function never actually runs.

Comment: yes I have called the function `test` at the end of the `trial.js` file but this still doesn't work.  That is when I started to think I needed a specific function like `addEventListener` for this.  I've edited my post to show this.

Comment: As I was double checking the files, I found that the manifest path was off.  So the `chrome.extension.getURL()` method did the trick.  Really appreciate the help, Thanks!

Comment: You might want to update the method in your answer as it's been deprecated: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling your extension with **webpack**, and images are being included via CSS (even in included libraries), add a webpack rule for images and such with type 'asset/inline'. They will be converted to Data URLs in the CSS.
I tried to have it find them at the chrome extension URL but it said can't load chrome-extension://invalid/. I set the publicPath option in webpack. might have been doing it wrong.

See this for an **example**: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#assets