# Google Chrome Extension for interacting with a web application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

hope somebody understand and can maybe explain me my idea.

My Goal:
I would like that the user can use my web application, but the requests for parsing urls, etc will not run on my server, but
are processed on the client side via the browser.

My theoretical example:

There is a web application the user need to login.

If the user is logged in, he can paste ten urls into a textinput box and than push a button.

Then a ajax request is made to the server and the urls are parsed and the site informations from the parsed urls comes back as json to display it in the frontend.

Ok now my real question.

Is it possible to create a Google Chrome Extension that catches the Post request from the textarea, and send the urls to the
background.js. than the background.js should request this urls via javascript xmlhttprequest to bypass the cross-orgin restriction.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. In fact, there are many ways to implement it. Here's a good answer to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526995/can-a-site-invoke-a-browser-extension.