# How do I retrieve post from browser extension?

Tags: php, javascript, post, curl, crossrider

How can I collect post data from a browser extension in php? Can you just collect it like a form? 
like this?:

```
echo $_POST["changes"];
```

I dont think that works though and I have no idea why.

Comment: Only function coming to my mind this time is `get_browser()` to fetch info about what browser is capable of doing..but for that make sure about `browscap configuration setting in php.ini`....let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: no im just looking to see how i retrieve the data

Comment: retrieve data from what?? a form or from a browser?? from browser extension??..if it is browser extension I believe u need some JS to work for that..you can check this if it is the case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526995/can-a-site-invoke-a-browser-extension