# How do I pass back data from a remote window to a chrome extension's background page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have a chrome extension, and from my background page I open a remote window:

```
chrome.windows.create({
        type : 'popup',
        url : "https://www.example.com/mypage.html"
    }, function(newWindow) {

    });
```

On my remote page (https://www.example.com/mypage.html) I am waiting for the user to perform an action. When this action is performed, I need to pass back to the extension some data.

How can I do this? I could not find anything relevant in the docs (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

Comment: Use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: @RobW thanks.Tried the "Sending messages from web pages" part but I get that "'externally_connectable' requires Google Chrome dev channel or newer, and this is the stable channel.".How can this work in production? It is strange that I cannot find a complete example for this kind of communication, if you have one it would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526995/can-a-site-invoke-a-browser-extension

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is basically possible. What you should do is to use the content script as a bridge between your newly created window and your background script. For example:

Your background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("message received");
});
chrome.windows.create({
    type : 'popup',
    url : "http://yoursite.com/page.html",
    type: "popup"
}, function(newWindow) {

});
```

Your content script:

```
document.addEventListener("hello", function(data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("test");
})
```

*page.html*:

```
<script>
    var go = function() {
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('hello');
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:go();">Click me</a>
```

So, the idea is to dispatch an event from the page using document object. The content script listens for that event and once occur send a message to the background script where your code is originally.

Comment: Important to note that yoursite.com must be included in manifest.json file under "content_scripts"... "matches": [ here ]. Your answer saved me a headache, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe messaging isn't necessary for what you're doing.  (Unless I'm missing something.)  I'm experimenting with creating an extension, and needed to create a popup to query the user for some information. At first I used messaging, then I read the following page:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html

Include a js in your html page which uses either extension.getBackgroundPage or runtime.getBackgroundPage [use the latter if you're using a non-persistent background page] to get at the background script.  It could be as easy invoking a function on your background page like this:

extension.getBackgroundPage().sendDataOrWhateverYouCallIt(data);