# Can I get the value of a variable from another script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Can I get the value of a variable from another script using content script? For example from a script on Facebook. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but based on the fact that you need to switch contexts or whatever, in the dev tools console, I'd say you can't, they're probably separate environments.

Comment: I think you can have a content script inject a `<script>` element into the page. The page will run that script. That script can read the value and then use DOM events to pass the value to the the content script. The steps are similar to those in [Can a site invoke a browser extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10526995/710446), but your injected script will be running functions itself, instead of declaring functions for the page to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content script can inject a `<script>` element into the page. That injected script should read the value and use DOM events to pass the value to the content script.

In your **content script**:

```
// inject a script from the extension's files
// into the execution environment of the main page
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("value _reader.js");
document.documentElement.appendChild(s);

document.addEventListener("valueFromPageEvent", function(event) {
    console.log("the content script just got the value " + event.detail.val);
});
```

Inside **`value_reader.js`** (which we injected in the content script above), assuming we want to the read the variable **`foobar`** from the page:

```
var dataObj = { "val": foobar };
var storeEvent = new CustomEvent('valueFromPageEvent', { "detail": dataObj });
document.dispatchEvent(storeEvent);
```

**N.B.:** The `value_reader.js` script must be in your extension's list of [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in the manifest.

Comment: Note: this method can fail if the page in question has a restrictive CSP.

Comment: @Xan An important note and an interesting problem. Perhaps you could get around this for specific services by using `webRequest` to alter `.js` files to include your event-emitting code? You'd have to make a tailor-made solution for each service you wanted to hijack, though, specifying which `.js` file to inject and when to fire the event.