# Communication between web page and service_worker (both ways)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a *Chrome Extension* which is structured like this :

- the **service_worker** : fetches a list of compatible websites every day and if it is compatible, I will inject a 'widget' in the website
- the **widget** : is a *React App* injected inside the page (a 300x300px `position:absolute` div) that can help the user and that is linked to the user account from **my** website, for example he can save a product from Amazon and see it later in his account in my website.

My problem is the communication between these two parts.
An example :
I want to check if the user has currently a session opened in my website, if yes, in the *React App* (the widget) I will render him some tools and his items, and if not I will render him a link to login in my website.

**Tried solutions**:

- **Call my website API directly from the widget** : but I dont want to make the verification from the widget because it is a part of the webpage and I am afraid of a *cookie/token hijacking* (tell me if i'm wrong).
- **Using CustomEvents to get a response** : I found [this useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526995/can-a-site-invoke-a-browser-extension), the problem is that as said in the 5th point I cant really wait for a response from the `service_worker` and store it.
- **Using CustomEvents with callbacks** : I also can't send a callback function as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824921/sending-custom-event-with-callback-to-content-script).
- **Using sendMessage from Chrome API** : To use this between webpage and the `service_worker` you need to specify in the manifest.json the pattern of every website that needs to use it, but the list can change every day. Also the domain cannot be `*`, and we cannot use `<all_urls>`

So, my communication is only working from the web page to the extension but not in the opposite way.

Can you advise me a way of making this work ?
Thanks !

Comment: Point #5 actually shows how to wait for a response, so just use it. OTOH I would recommend an entirely different approach: embed a web_accessible_resources iframe with your react app inside (a generic example is [shown here](/a/25100953), but you can also find a react component for web_accessible_resources iframes). This iframe can make the network requests directly without the page knowing.

Comment: Thanks for (all) your answer @wOxxOm
So you say that any ajax call made inside the iframe is not catchable by the page ?
And that it is safe from XSS/hijacking in my case ?

Comment: Yes, it runs in a different OS process.